# Getting the percentage symbol to output

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've searched to try and find an answer to this incredibly simple question, but I can't find it anywhere online.

I have the following JavaScript:

```
m = ((((r-c)/r) * 100).toFixed(2))  //outputs 15.01        
$('#margin').val("%" + m);
```

The value that gets output to `#margin` is `/15.01` instead of `%15.01`

Why is JavaScript outputting a `/` instead of the `%` symbol that I'm asking it to output?

Comment: Well, works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nht4kcgy/). Can you reproduce it on fiddle or something?

Comment: What element is your margin ?

Comment: Huge sigh.  The FONT I'm using replaces `%` with `/`.  Incredible.

Comment: that truly is an ugly little bug